Как получить результат работы pprint в виде строки?
Возможно, вопрос звучит странно, но я не знаю как это можно переформулировать. Предположим, что есть список:
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Я знаю, что можно получить красивый вывод с помощью pprint:
pprint(lst)
...
[
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5
]

Но можно -ли как-нибудь получить такой же результат в виде строки, Например как-нибудь так:
beauty_lst = pprint_return(lst)
print(beauty_lst)
...
[
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5
]
 


На англоязычном СО пишут, что для этого можно использовать pprint.pformat.

Спасибо, это то, что я искал

Нет, что-то именно как вы хотели там не получается всё-равно кажется :/  Впрочем, pprint тоже в одну строку печатает ваш список. Я что-то не соображу, как его в отдельные строки разнести )

Почему, все так, списки форматируются в более красиыйвый вид с переносом строк

Хм, ну ок. У меня в Jupyter Notebook в одну строку ваш список печатается )  Ну раз что надо, то ок )

@CrazyElf width=1 в параметр добавить и будет то что нужно.
